# Запрет конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания

Tags: c++

Как запретить использование конструктора копирования и оператора присваивания? Т.е. так чтобы классом мог пользоваться только другой класс, а в main нельзя было создать экземпляр этого класса.

В main компилироваться не должен, а в другом классе это было бы возможно:

```
A a;
A a(b);
A a=b;
```

Comment: т.е. так чтобы экземпляр нельзя было создать в `main`

Comment: запрет конструктора копирования и присваивания не запретит создавать экземпляр класса. Как вариант поместить их в private.

Comment: надо сделать так чтобы классом мог пользоваться только другой класс, а в `main` вообще нельзя было создать

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно решить данную проблему с использованием дружественного класса:

```
class myClassClose{
   myClassClose(); //конструктор по умолчанию
   myClassClose(const myClassClose&); //конструктор копирования
   myClassClose(myClassClose&&); //конструктор перемещения
   myClassClose operator = (const myClassClose&) const; //оператор присваивания
   myClassClose operator = (myClassClose&&) const; //оператор присваивания с перемещением
public:
   friend class myClass;
};

class myClass{
    myClassClose a;
  public:
    myClass(){}
};
```

Comment: что за перенос?

Comment: @Fllw Он имел в виду "оператор перемещения"

Comment: @StateItPrimitive, да, спасибо

Comment: @Fllw новинка C++11: rvalue-ссылки и семантика идеальной передачи (гарантия отсутствия лишнего копирования). [На хабре можно частично вникнуть.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/226229/)